# Dependencies for using Model Validation in ASP.NET Core App

Tags: asp.net-core

I make use of the the model validation feature like this:

```
[StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
[Required]
```

But when I start the application I get this:

```
Author.cs(8,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StringLengthAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Author.cs(8,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StringLength' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Author.cs(9,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RequiredAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Author.cs(9,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Required' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Author.cs(8,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MinimumLength' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Author.cs(11,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StringLengthAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Author.cs(11,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StringLength' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Author.cs(12,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RequiredAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Author.cs(12,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Required' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Author.cs(11,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MinimumLength' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I cannot find out what package I'm missing. My guess was `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations` but that seems not to be it.

So what dependency do I need here?

Comment: Seems correct, did you import the correct namespace? Should be `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` or `using System.ComponentModel.Annotations`. Just  hit `Ctrl`+`.` on the error to let VS suggest you a namespace

Comment: Yea, I forgot the `using`! Many thanks

Comment: I posted the comment as as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependency seems correct.

But just importing the library/nuget package doesn't mean you can just use it. You also need to put `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` (or `using System.ComponentModel.Annotations` at the top of your *.cs file.

Or just hit `Ctrl`+`.` on the error to let VS suggest you the correct namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first install entity framework from the nuget package then only you will be able to get the using System.ComponentModel.Annotations.